# Previous repo owner never pushed to remote. How can I preserve git commit history, made by that user, when I take over the repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Basically, the previous owner of this repo did two years of local commits, and never did a push to remote that entire time. I am the new owner of the repo, and need to preserve that previous user's commit history, but also create MY new commit history going forward.

The repo was given to me by copying the entire local directory tree to my machine, so I have the previous owner's .git directory/files, but I don't know how to say 'keep all that previous user's commits (and especially let me push it all to remote, at bitbucket)... but all new commits belong to my username'.

I'm pretty experienced with git, but I've just never seen this situation before and don't want to wreck this very important repo. Advice?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. The commits are already made; git does not have a concept of "who actually pushed the commit to remote" so your name won't be associated with them at all.

Comment: I agree with @o11c. So, in other words, push what you have, all the commits will stay with the previous username/email address at the time each commit was made. Set your username/email and all commits you do will have your name on them.